# How to open New Tab Panel in Atom Editor

Tags: javascript, package, atom-editor

**I can open a new tab like this:**

```
atom.workspace.open(uri, option)
```

**but it is just a text editor tab, i need a Panel that can editable with divs buttons etc.**

**So:**

**Is there a way to open a panel like this but in a New Tab:**

```
atom.workspace.addRightPanel() //or Left, Bottom..
```

**Thanks.**

Comment: did you try this: https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.14.2/AtomEnvironment#instance-open ?

Comment: @bens i ve checked but it looks like about Atom itself not Tab panels

Comment: I had a proper look at all the documentation but still nothing. I think for now there is no way! However, you should get in touch with them as this could be useful!

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: @sexta13 you can reach my solution under this repository but it hasn't been worked after a while with Atom's new versions. I dont  know why.
https://github.com/chnselim/atom-referenceseeker